# Map a domain to subdomain from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, subdomain

I have a rails application where clients can create their own environment.

For example a client gets his own environment at a subdomain:
client.domain.com

But I want them to be able to map their own domain to the subdomain from my domain

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an association table between an arbitrary hostname and the customer so that you can convert between one and the other. This could either be a stand-alone table, or a field on the customer record.

It's pretty straight-forward to load this instead of using the subdomain method. Just be sure to pre-populate the field with the existing names you're using.

Comment: My explanation wasn't that good. But what I mean is when a customer wants to use intranet.domain.com to point to their subdomain on my application. So in the example of intranet.domain.com, this domain will go to client.myapp.com

Comment: You can do that with an HTTP-level redirect, typically, something either you or your customer can facilitate. You'll need the same association table and do a `redirect_to(customer_subdomain)` type response. The customer will have to add a DNS record that maps to your server, so a CNAME record is typically best.